# sound level bar visualizer for music player

Tags: android, audio

I need to build a sound level bar. as the sound goes up the level of the sound rises.
It's kind of like a visualizer but as a bar. like this :

https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/disco-lightning/id893088657?mt=8

you can see the the level bar in the link above.

I hope i could ask my question right. thanks

Comment: Well, exactly what _is_ your question? _"I need some code that does X"_ is not a question. What have you tried so far and what specific problem did you run into?

Comment: As you saw the picture, I need some code to perform like a sound bar visualizer based on db of the sound. like as the db rises the levelbar goes up and when the db is decreased the levelbar goes down.

Answer (score 0):

The most valid way to show the power of sound is calculate RMS.
Get a portion of the samples (for example 4096 samples) and calculate RMS for them.
 RMS is calculated as RMS = sqrt(1/N*(X1^2 + X2^2 + X3^3 ...... Xn^2)) where N is the number of samples and X are the values of the samples. After calculating RMS you can normalize the value and draw a rectangle. 
Do not try to calculate average instead of RMS. Average will be always near zero because of the negative sample values. 
If computation time is problem you can go with average of the absolute values of samples but this value is 10% different of RMS (for sinusoidal wave) so you can multiply it with 1.11 after that, to get something close to RMS. At the end, even if you don't multiply with 1.11, nobody will notice that there is 10% difference...